# Why won't v-for put out more profiles so I have an infinite scroll like effect?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I have a firestore database where I am getting profiles from and then using v-for to show them all on a page but I want to put an infinite scroll in for better user experience.
This is my javascript composable code

```
import { projectFirestore } from "../Firebase/Config";
import { ref } from "vue"

const getPremium = () => {
    const Premium = ref([])
    const error = ref(null)

    
const load = async () => {
    try{
        const res = await projectFirestore.collection('Premium').limit(4).get()
        

        Premium.value = res.docs.map(doc => {
           console.log(doc.data())
           return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
        })
    }
    catch (err){
        error.value = err.message
        console.log(error.value)
    }
    const newPicturesCount = await load()
    if (newPicturesCount > 0) {
        return load() // More profiles to come
      }

      return console.log("done") // Done with the profiles
    }

    return { Premium, error, load }
}

export default getPremium
```

What I expected was that it would then v-for the rest of the results and make it so that the first profiles would load and then the next to make user experience better and with less load times but the profiles are being console logged as they load but they are not appearing in the v-for statement as I expected they would and it appears to get the same 4 profiles over and over which isn't what I want heres the vue end for a full picture.

```
<div v-for =" Premiums in Premium" :key="Premiums.id" >
 <router-link :to="{ name: 'Samplepremium', params: { id: Premiums.id }}">
 <div class= "hover:scale-105 transition ease-in-out duration-300 bg-neutral-800 hover:bg-neutral-900 active:bg-neutral-900 text-neutral-400 font-bold rounded-xl">
  <br>
     <p class="text-xl">{{ Premiums.Name }}</p>
     <div class="relative">
     <img :src= "Premiums.Pic1"  class="object-contain px-1 inline-block w-96 h-44 md:w-60 md:h-80 lg:w-60 lg:h-80 xl:w-60 xl:h-80 2xl:w-60 2xl:h-80 transition ease-in-out duration-300">
     <p class="bg-red-700 text-slate-300 text-xl absolute top-0 w-full">{{ Premiums.detail1 }}</p>
     <p class="bg-red-700 text-slate-300 text-xl absolute bottom-0 w-full"> {{ Premiums.detail2 }} </p>
    </div>
     <div class="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-fit text-left ml-6">
     <p>Age:</p>
     <p>{{ Premiums.detail3 }}</p>
     <p>Location:</p>
     <p>{{ Premiums.detail4 }}</p>
     <p>Rates:</p>
     <p>{{ Premiums.detail5 }} /hr</p>
     <p>Phone:</p>
     <p>{{ Premiums.detail6 }}</p>
   
    </div><br>
  </div>
  </router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to keep track of the document I'm up to and how to v-for profiles after the initial for I'd really appreciate it Thanks.

Comment: `I expected was that it would then v-for the rest of the results` why? you always `projectFirestore.collection('Premium').limit(4).get()` why would that get anything different than the first 4?

Comment: const newPicturesCount = await load()
    if (newPicturesCount > 0) {
        return load() // More profiles to come
      } I expected these lines to then get another 4 once it reached here?

Comment: why do you think that? does `await projectFirestore.collection('Premium').limit(4).get()` return a different 4 items each time?

Comment: No I surpose not , I guess what I'm asking then is how could I keep track of the document I'm up to and then when the load function runs again start at that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your implementation is wrong. what `load()` is doing is to fetch four profiles from firebase and re valuing `Premium` with the value provided from firebase. So, by calling load, you fetch every time same values, and every time previous data will overwrites to the new one, so the previous data lost.

What you have to do is to use a cursor, and add data to Premium value.

Modify the `getPremium()`:

```
const getPremium = () => {
    const Premium = ref([])
    const error = ref(null)
    let lastDoc = null; 

    const load = async () => {
        try {
            let query = projectFirestore.collection('Premium').orderBy('id').limit(4)
            if (lastDoc) {
                query = query.startAfter(lastDoc)
            }

            const res = await query.get()

            if (!res.empty) {
                lastDoc = res.docs[res.docs.length - 1]

                // Add new results to exsiting ones

                Premium.value = [...Premium.value, ...res.docs.map(doc => {
                    console.log(doc.data())
                    return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
                })]
            }
        }
        catch (err){
            error.value = err.message
            console.log(error.value)
        }
    }

    return { Premium, error, load }
}

export default getPremium
```

Remember to add `import { projectFirestore } from "../Firebase/Config";` and `import { ref } from "vue"`.

Now simply use `@scroll` to your html part:

```
<div @scroll="checkScroll" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 100vh;">
    <div v-for="Premiums in Premium" :key="Premiums.id" >
        <!-- your html goes here -->
    </div>
    <button v-if="isLoading" type="button">Loading...</button>
</div>
```

and:

```
checkScroll() {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            this.load(); 
    }
}
```

pretty straight forward, right?
Hope this helps